# In Javascript, if an object has a key which is a character, can the .length of that key ever be anything other than 1?

Tags: javascript, key

Assume we have a string `unknownStr` with an unknown value that is not `undefined` and not `null`.

Assume we then have this code:

```
var chrArray = [];
var keyValObject = {};
var keyLength;
for (var i = 0; i < unknownStr.length; i++) { chrArray.push(unknownStr[i]); }
for (var i = 0; i < chrArray.length; i++) { keyValObject[chrArray[i]] = "foo"; }
for (var key in keyValObject) { keyLength = key.length; }
```

Is it possible that `keyLength` will ever have a value other than `1`?

Comment: shouldn't that be "for (var i = 0; i < unknownStr.length; i++)" ?

Comment: Yes - consider extending `Object.prototype`.

Comment: What's the point of this question? A one character string will always have the length one (aside from possible modifications of built in data types).

Comment: totally unrelated to the answer you need, but what is the end goal of this code? it looks a bit like you are trying to get a character frequency count of some kind... just wondering if we can help you get to your goal in an easier way? ;-)

Comment: To be pendantic, `unknownStr` could also just be an array, rendering the question a bit unanswerable.

Comment: @Kristian yep, good catch - updated

Comment: @FelixKling i have seen code where they treat the length like it could be a value other than one, which doesn't make sense to me, thus this question :)

Comment: @pimvdb to be clear, you're saying a scenario in which the length could have a value other than 1 is IF someone extended object prototype?  this makes sense

Comment: @scunliffe it's representative of a code snippet from a large library i'm digesting, so rather than provide verbose context, I tried to make it simple and abstract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and can be demonstrated as follows

```
Object.prototype.longKey = "foo";
```

Now all objects will have the property `longKey` including `keyValObject`.  Because you don't restrict the `key` value in the `for` loop to `hasOwnProperty` it will eventually see `longKey` which has a length greater than 1

Comment: So for this answer and pimvdb's comment above, it sounds like the only scenario in which this could occur is if the `object.prototype` was extended AND you did not check for `hasOwnProperty` when selecting the key?

Comment: .. in addition, since prototyping is still a new concept to me, can you confirm my understanding that if `object.prototype` had been extended as in your code snippet, would `keyValObject` automatically have a `key` `longKey` with a `value` of `"foo"` as soon as it was instantiated via `var keyValObject = {};`?

Comment: @chopperdave yes, that is the case.